# NumberFormatException when running a calculator program with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, numberformatexception

I am trying to program a simple calculator.

```
public static String cal(){
        String a="-60-1+40";
        if(a.matches("-?[1-9][0-9]?([\\+-][1-9][0-9]?)+")){
            System.out.println(a);
            String operators[]=a.split("[0-9]+");
            String operands[]=a.split("[+-]");
            int agregate = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
            for(int i=1;i<operands.length;i++){
                if(operators[i].equals("+"))
                    agregate += Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
                else 
                    agregate -= Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
            }
             return Integer.toString(agregate);
        }else throw new invalidExpressionException(a+" is a Invalid expression");
    }
```

I have this function but when I try to run it I get a `NumberFormatException` if the first character of the string is a `"-"`. All other cases seems to be right and only that one is failing. I've been trying to fix for a while but I don't find how.

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
-60-1+40
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at calculator.Calculator.cal(Calculator.java:20)
    at calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:9)
```

Comment: an empty String is not a numerical value, and can not be parsed to one. That's exactly what that error message is saying

Comment: But i don't understand why does it fail when the string is -60-1+40, but when it is 60-1+40 is fine

Comment: You are splitting on `-` which will leave you with an empty first element. It's the same as if you would write `60+-1` which would result in `"60", "", "1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Ben's comment, a workaround would be to check if the first character is a '`-`', and in that case preppend a `0` to the string before processing it (-n can be obtained as sustracting the number n from 0):

`-1+2-3`, should become `0-1+2-3`

```
if(a.startsWith("-")){
    a = "0" + a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

```
public static String calculator(){
    String a="-60-1+40";
    if(a.matches("-?[1-9][0-9]?([\\+-][1-9][0-9]?)+")){
        System.out.println(a);
        String operators[]=a.split("[0-9]+");
        String operands[]=a.split("[+-]");
        int agregate = operands[0].isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);//changed code
        for(int i=1;i<operators.length;i++){//operators.length is better
            if(operators[i].equals("+"))
                agregate += Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
            else 
                agregate -= Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
        }
         return Integer.toString(agregate);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Go ahead check ur test cases. Let us know if any of them needs to be covered

Comment: you may want to explain what you changed and why

Comment: In this code you are trying to cast empty string in integer which will not work,

Comment: At `operands[0]` you will get empty string if you put (-) in start of string.

Comment: This worked to fix the exception but the calculation was not being doing correctly, like the result was always the first number of the string, ie: -6+1= -6 or 6+1=6 but the solution @Juan gave worked!!

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

The short answer is that you can filter out the empty strings like this. The Streams are relatively new API and it might be tricky to write them. I believe, however, that they are easy to read. So here it is:

```
        String operands[] = Arrays.stream(calculateCommand.split("[+-]"))
                .filter(str -> str != null && 0 < str.trim().length()) // skipping the empty elements
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

#### Trolling answer

```
public static String cal() {
    String a = "-60-1+40"; // a reminder for the developer
    return "-21"; // a correct answer for the input above
}
```

There is a trolling answer here. As long as the function always returns the same, you can go ahead with this shortcut:

#### Rework

None of the fixes above are giving you what you want. I gave up fixing that method. Instead I wrote another function:

```
// letting the reader know that this calculator can deal with + and - only
public static String additiveCalculator(String calculateCommand) {
    if (calculateCommand == null) {
        // input handling
        throw new NullPointerException("cannot calculate null string");
    }
    if (calculateCommand.startsWith("-")) {
        // dealing with only one case
        return additiveCalculator("0" + calculateCommand);
    }
    if (! calculateCommand.matches("\\d+(\\s*[+-]\\s*\\d+)*")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input '" + calculateCommand + "' is not calculable.");
    }
    Integer[] operands = Arrays.stream(calculateCommand.split("[+-]"))
            .map(str -> str.trim())
            .map(str -> Integer.parseInt(str))
            .toArray(Integer[]::new);
    String[] operators = calculateCommand.replaceAll("[^+-]", "").split("");
    int aggregate = operands[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
        int num = operands[i+1];
        String op = operators[i];
        switch (op) {
            case "+":
                aggregate += num;
                break;
            case "-":
                aggregate -= num;
                break;
            default:
                // this can't happen. However, later this exception might be useful
                throw new IllegalStateException("The " + i + "th operator, '" + op + "' is not an additive operator.");
        }
    }
    return Integer.toString(aggregate);
}
```

I added comments to point out the improvements. I'd like to explain the number checker regex though. It was `\\d+(\\s*[+-]\\s*\\d+)*`. Here is the explanation:

- `\\d` stands for numbers. Equivalent with `[0-9]`
- `\\s` stands for white spaces.
- `\\d+` The regex starts with a number, that can be zero too. No need to add the `^` because we use `String.matches()`.
- `(...)*` then we can see zero or more of:
- `\\s*[+-]\\s*\\d+` - some spaces, an operator, some more spaces, then a number